# Why doesn't this Oracle DATE comparison work

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

In Oracle 12, if I create a very simple table, `TEST_TABLE`, with a single `varchar2(128)` column 'name' and populate that column with lots of strings of `'20170831'`, and my `sysdate` shows:

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual;

29-SEP-17
```

then why does this SQL query return 0 rows:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(name,'YYYYMMDD'), 
       TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')
    FROM TEST_TABLE
    WHERE TO_DATE(name,'YYYYMMDD') < TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

(This is a very simplified example of a problem I'm facing in my partition maintenance script and have not been able to solve for the last week).
Thank you in advance for any assistance related to the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't apply a `to_date()` to an already date field, this because, it will implicitly convert that date into varchar and then apply the `to_date()` function to it, for example your query part `TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')` is interpreted like this:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

`TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE))` is getting a char something like: '31-AUG-17', and that is not in 'DD-MM-YYYY' format. 
And because of that, `TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')` gets something like this: 29/09/0017 and your filter goes FALSE and gets no results.

Comment: Thank you!  In my real partition maintenance script I still get an error.  My partitions are all named with a format like 'R_DATE_20170831'.  When I run the query:

Comment: SELECT count(*)
      FROM dba_tab_partitions
     WHERE table_owner = 'myID'
       AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR(partition_name,INSTR(partition_name,'_',1,2) + 1),'YYYYMMDD') < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
I keep getting:

Comment: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range

Comment: My NLS_DATE_FORMAT has a value of:  DD-MON-RR

Comment: @scotto If your `SUBSTR` function doesn't match 'YYYYMMDD' in any `partition_name` field in any place, then your `TO_DATE('YYYYMMDD')` will fail to parse the date. To avoid this, you should prefilter, something like this: `SELECT count(*) FROM dba_tab_partitions WHERE table_owner = 'myID' AND partition_name <> 'ERROR' and TO_DATE(SUBSTR(partition_name,INSTR(partition_name,'_',1,2) + 1),'YYYYMMDD') < TRUNC(SYSDATE);`

Where ERROR partition usually is the initial or default partition.

Answer (score 1):

Midnight(time part is 00:00:00.000):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(name,'YYYYMMDD'), TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE TO_DATE(name,'YYYYMMDD') <= TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

You could also try:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: `SYSDATE` is already of `date` data type. there is no need to apply `TO_DATE()` function, otherwise, SYSDATE undergoes double conversion    - from date to character and then back to date.